# Text Widget to Show database fields based on post

Tags: widgets

I am wondering whether this is possible:

- I would like a widget which displays fields taken from a database table I have created.

Table contains information about the location of the post.

Widget to show the information about the post location based on a custom field in the post e.g

Post Custom Field Location = London

Widget to show text about London (stored in the database)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a plugin that does this, but here's an alternative:

You can use code like this to get the post's metadata (custom field) values in the widget sidebar.php:

```
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebarval', $single = true); ?>
<?php if($sidebar != '') { ?>
    <?php $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE col = " . $sidebar );
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. DO I replace 'sidebarval' with my custom_field 'location'.. TO to echo the results?

Comment: Yes, the "sidebarval" would be the variable that goes in the left custom field box (Name) and the $sidebar php variable will be the contents of that custom field (Value). There's a lot more you can do here - this is just a simple example.

Comment: sorry I might be missing the trick here... I have put the following code in a PHP Widget in my side bar:

    <?php global $post; ?>

    <?php $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'venue',  $single = true); ?>
    <?php if($sidebar != '') { ?>
    <?php $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM wp_venues WHERE name = " . $sidebar);
    <?php } ?>
    <? echo $sidebar; ?>

What am I missing?

Comment: ok fixed that thanks.. 

<? global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT name FROM wp_venues WHERE name ='".the_field('venue')."' ";
$info = $wpdb->get_var($querystr);
echo $info;
?>